# Is there a more effective way to use streams to get the average from an int column in a ResultSet (Java)

Tags: java, java-stream

I am currently trying to use streams to get the average from a column of int in a ResultSet, however the only way I can make this work is by first putting the numbers into a List and using .stream() on that list.

Is there a more direct way to accomplish this?

```
public void avgSalaryAbove150k(Connection con) {

    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + schemaName + "."+tableName+" WHERE EMPLOYEE_SALARY>150000";
    List<Integer>salaries = new ArrayList<>();


    try(
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            ){
            while(rs.next()) {

                int salary = rs.getInt("EMPLOYEE_SALARY");

                salaries.add(salary);

            }
            System.out.println("Now showing average salary of employees with a salary of over 150,000...");
            salaries.stream()
            .mapToInt((x)->x)
            .average()
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);
            System.out.println("");

        }catch(SQLException ex) {

            System.out.println("Failed to create the database  connection.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

The method currently works in this from but I have the distinct feeling this is not the best way of doing this.

Comment: This is not the most efficient way to get an average salary.  If you write the query so the database calculates it you save yourself having to bring all those records to the server side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the average calculation to the SQL query itself, so that you don't need to use Java Streams at all.

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT avg(EMPLOYEE_SALARY) FROM " + schemaName + "."+tableName+" WHERE EMPLOYEE_SALARY>150000";
```

Then you can read the single row returned in the `ResultSet`, making sure to retrieve the value as a `double`.